# How to Find Joint PDF of X and Y?

Tags: probability

I have that $(X,Y)∼U(E)$ where $E$ is the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $y=x$, $y=2x$, $y=\frac{1}{x}$, and $y=\frac{2}{x}$.
Firstly, I need to find the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$. Secondly, I need to Find the probability that the distance from a random point chosen from $E$ to the origin is less than $\sqrt5$.

Answer (score 2):

For a uniform distribution, the PDF is just $\frac{1}{area(E)}$ inside the region $E$, and $0$ outside of it (check to see that it matches what your intuition expects).

For the second probability - try looking at the intersection of the region $E$ with a circle of radius $\sqrt5$ from the origin. The probabilty you're looking for is the area of interesction divided by the total area of $E$.

In general, when dealing with uniform distribution, the idea is - the probabilty of a certain region is the area of that region divided by the area of the probability space. The intuition behind this is that if any point is equally probable, then all you should care about is the area, and not how its divided in the probability space (at least in the simple cases).